# jQuery not reloading a div by class, id, or class AND id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user submits the form, the information and form works but the div box is not reloading. I've used .atten, #tag, and .atten#tag. it's simply not grabbing the div box.

```
<div class = 'atten' id = 'tag'>
formm is in here
</div>

echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.atten').on('click', function(){
        var tag = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.atten').submit(false);
        $.post('atten_form.php',
                $('.atten#' + tag).serialize(),             
            function (data, status){
                $('#div' + tag).load(' #div' + tag);
                })
        });
});
</script>";
```

Comment: tag is a variable in php and is used for div id since there are many tags on the page and each has it's own designated form.

Comment: You are attaching `submit` handler on `div`?

Comment: What is `$('.atten').submit(false);` supposed to do? Passing a boolean to `.submit()` doesn't make sense, and calling `.submit()` for a `<div>` doesn't make sense either.

Comment: it should be like this `$('div#' + tag).load('div#' + tag);`

Comment: there are 3 vague parts in your code: `.submit(false)` //what is this supposed to do. `load()` and the serverside code or response is missing.

Comment: also make sure there is only 1 html element with the id `tag` otherwise it will take the first HtmlElement it can find.

Comment: Sorry! I should clarify that I JUST started learning jquery this weekend.

First: the entire website was PHP only so a lot of forms on here. The .submit was to disable going to the page where the form info gets used.

I just changed the class and id of the form and div so they are both different.

Comment: Everythign works like it's supposed to EXCEPT the load.

Answer (score 0):

`load` function is for Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element for more detail read [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

If you want to load data from a element that is on current page then simply use `.html()` function.

```
$('div#' + tag).html($('div#' + tag).html());
```

Here is example:

```js
  $('.atten').on('click', function() {
     var tag = $(this).attr('id');
     $('div#' + tag).html($('div#' + tag).html()+ " content loaded");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atten' id='tag'>
  formm is in here
</div>
```

Comment: That would explain why when I used the load, the entire page loaded inside the div and ended up with a cascade of pages.

inside the div, is the form I used for .post. but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
This was the solution:

    "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('click', '.atten', function(el){ //changed from form id .atten to body.
    var tag = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.atten').submit(false);
    $.post('atten_form.php',
            $('.atten#' + tag).serialize(),             
        function (data, status){
            $('#divWrap' + tag).load(' #atten' + tag); //added an additional div around the div with id atten$tag.
            });
    })
 })

</script>";
```